# Show that the norm of this operator is equal to 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P$ a projection $H \rightarrow H$ ( a bounded linear operator on $H$ such that $P^2=P$ and $P$ is not equal to $0$)

I showed that $ ||P|| \ge 1$ and that $P$ is auto adjoint. I also know that $||P^*P|| = ||P||^2$ where $P^*$ is the adjoint of $P$

How can I now show that $||P||=1$ ?

Comment: Use the Pythagorean theorem?  Show that $\|Px\|$ is the side length of a right triangle, whose hypotenuse has length $\|x\|$.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to show it using only these properties

Comment: There are nonorthogonal projections $P^2=P$.  Orthogonal projections are those which also satisfies $P^*=P$.  Then you have $(I-P^*)P=0$ so $Px\perp (I-P)x$, etc.

Comment: You are correct, I edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it.

$||P^*P|| = ||P^2||= ||P||$

but also : $||P^*P||=||P||^2$

so, since $||P|| \ge 1$, it must be equal to $1$